# Divide and conquer: Merging theoretical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, and quantum-mechanics

Tags: discussion, tags

Do the scopes of the tags [theoretical-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theoretical-chemistry), [quantum-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-chemistry), and [quantum-mechanics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-mechanics) differ noticably enough in order to keep them all or can we merge two of them? IMHO, the [quantum-mechanics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-mechanics) tag is well suited for questions about the foundations and the more mathematical aspects of quantum theory that might have no direct connection to chemical systems, e.g. questions like [this one](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/10571/189), [this one](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/10630/189), or [this one](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/10918/189). That leaves [theoretical-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theoretical-chemistry) and [quantum-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-chemistry) for questions with a more chemistry-related background: But I think we don't need both of them and should merge [quantum-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-chemistry) into [theoretical-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theoretical-chemistry) since the latter one is a little more general. But I'm not working directly in the field of Theoretical Chemistry so there may be reasons for keeping the tags seperate.

Comment: The theoretical chemistry tag is used in a different context here. It may cover theories in general. While the quantum tags are dealing with more specific Subfields. I think all these tags are quite well established and we should keep them. But i admit that these tags are quite similar and a proper assignment is difficult.

Comment: @Martin What do you think about merging [tag:quantum-mechanics] and [tag:quantum-chemistry]? While mathematically-oriented questions might not exactly fit into [tag:quantum-chemistry] those things are usually part of university courses on Quantum Chemistry or could be considered as being related to the field. And since this is Chemistry.SE I don't think we will get a whole lot of questions about Quantum Mechanics that wouldn't fit into [tag:quantum-chemistry] while still being on-topic here. "Physics" questions about, say, the Aharonov-Bohm-Effekt would be better suited Physics.SE anyway.

Answer (score 6):

After spending a few weeks in the community, I think [quantum-mechanics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-mechanics) and [quantum-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-chemistry) should be merged.

I'm less certain about theory vs. computational chemistry. Perhaps that distinction can be maintained, since one is about the actual theory and one is about carrying things out on a computer.

But in the case of the two quantum tags, I see a *lot* of confusion and most questions with one are tagged in the other as well.

I'm bringing this back up, since I think we really should merge the tags.

Comment: What do you think about merging the quantum tags into theo-chem? Or do you think they can be sufficiently distinguished? I am myself often confused whether to use the one term or the other.

Answer (score 4):

I generally (at least now) like the idea of merging [quantum-machanics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-machanics) and [quantum-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-chemistry) into [theoretical-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theoretical-chemistry).

---

However, the use of [theoretical-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theoretical-chemistry) is very vague and broad at the same time. It may deal with all sorts of different models and theories, at least judging from the scope of the questions, this is the use of this tag.

- orbitals: [Bonding in diatomic C2, a carbon-carbon quadruple bond?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/594/4945)
- solid state chemistry: [Are chiral quasicrystals possible?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/4271/4945)
- kinetics: [Definitions of autocatalysis](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/290/4945)
- nanotech: [What does the charge distribution around a Stone-Wales defect look like?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/379/4945)
- general terminology and their application: [What does "reaction coordinate" mean? What does it mean when a reaction has TWO reaction coordinates?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/456/4945)

Unfortunately the tag wiki is incomplete at best and the scope of these questions is just mentioned as:

> For questions seeking generalised answers deduced from or composed of theories regarding the chemical reactions involved.

We also have a [general](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general) without description and only 5 questions, while theo-chem has 55.

A lot of these questions also deal with models that would generally be considered [quantum-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-chemistry) or [physical-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical-chemistry). Appropriate retagging would be in order, as I think that theo-chem defines the scope of the questions best (in comparison within the range [organic-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/organic-chemistry), [inorganic-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inorganic-chemistry), ...).

We might then want to go ahead and create a tag like the proposed [general](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general), but with a more meaningful name, like general-theories, chemical-models, ... (I cannot think of good ones right now). But yet again I am not sure if we actually need that.

If we clean up this tag, i.e. removing it from those questions that fit better in other categories, then I think merging would be very well applicable.

---

In general I think that conjunctional tagging is more appropriate in most cases:

- [quantum-mechanics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-mechanics) is in the scope of [physical-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical-chemistry) and [theoretical-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theoretical-chemistry)
- [quantum-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-chemistry) is (almost always) in the scope of [computational-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-chemistry) and [theoretical-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theoretical-chemistry) and there are even more specific tags

Comment: Geoff restarted the discussion about this in another question.  Is this still how you feel it should go, or have things changed based on the current usage?