# Do we need [polymers] and [plastics] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Current usage guidance for [plastics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plastics) ([116 posts](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plastics))

> For questions relating to the structures, properties, production methods and potential hazards of **polymer materials** commonly known as plastics

Current usage guidance for [polymers](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polymers) ([369 posts](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polymers))

> For questions about synthetic or natural polymers, their chemical or physical properties, and their synthesis, etc.

([36 posts with both](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polymers+plastics))

The tags appear substantially redundant in their usage. Thus it seems logical to me that they do not need to coexist, and we could merge the wiki for [plastics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plastics) into [polymers](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polymers) and make [plastics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plastics) a synonym for [polymers](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polymers). Thoughts?

Comment: related: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/393/23561

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried that [a while ago](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/393/1) and even after reworking it, it got no momentum. And there still is [materials](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/materials) which also may include plastics and polymers.

I'm quoting thomij from that [post](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/397/4945):

> However, there are key differences in how they are defined scientifically.
>
> **Plastics** are defined based on their material properties - how do they respond to an applied stress?
>
> **Polymers** are defined based on their molecular structure - how are the atoms that make them up connected?

The usage probably does not reflect that currently, but just because there is a sloppy usage, it does not justify creating tag synonyms. It would be better creating more defined usage guidelines, and applying the tags according to these stricter.

**For now I disagree with the proposal.**

Comment: I would argue that materials is the broader field to be used with polymers, glass, ceramics, and metals tags and sometimes semiconductor. Similar to how [tag:analytical-chemistry] should be used with [tag:ftir]

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree with the suggestion. "[Plastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic)" is a popular synonym for polymer but actually describes a specific [behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasticity_(physics)). One good thing is that the word "plastic" is typically associated with synthetic polymers and allows distinction from [biopolymers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biopolymer), which form a very broad class of their own (and perhaps deserve their own tag?)

---

Aside: other useful terms that encompass "polymer" and may deserve their own tag are "macromolecules" and "colloid". "Colloid" in particular captures explicitly a connection between spatial dimension and physicochemical behavior which is lacking in "polymer". "Colloid" overlaps with "nanotechnology" but is largely distinct. It is however a somewhat old-fashioned term. Alternatives include "mesoscopic materials" and "soft matter" but these are less well known.

Comment: as far as bio polymers we have DNA-RNA and protien tags already. what other subcategory would you propose?

Comment: @A.K. Well, I can think of two common types of polymers: synthetic polymers and "biopolymers". The latter captures nucleic acids, proteins, plus carb-based polymers such as cellulose (most common natural polymer), amylose/pectin (starch), chitin, etc. It is more general. So if I were to propose a category: "biopolymer".

Comment: Colloids can 1.) be made of network solids and 2.) are physically defined thus for those reasons colloid is not accetable replacement for polymer.

Comment: I think the problem with macromolecule **with polymer as a synonym** is 1.) it sounds like a molecular focus only ignoring the special mechanical properties of polymers (polymer is a class of materials, macro-molecules is not) and 2.) it is not intuitive for the average user to search macromolecule instead of polymer.

Comment: @A.K. the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macromolecule) entry on macromolecule is worth a read. I never meant really to suggest macromolecule as an alternative or synonym to polymer, but rather as a word that describes large molecules including polymers, as an alternative to andselisk's suggestion of high MW molecules. I agree though that as a tag the word macromolecule might not be heavily used. I do like "biomolecule".

Comment: I can see that a polymer from a molecular prospective is technically correct to call a macromolecule. And yes macromolecule could be a tag, I just don't know how many questions if any bring up the subject at this time. As far a biomolecule goes I would consider it unnecessary since we have tags for [tag:lipids], [tag:proteins], and [tag:carbohydrates].

Answer (score 0):

I agree that [plastics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plastics) is redundant and [polymers](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polymers) is sufficient on its own. On the other hand, I would propose a "*high-molecular-weight-compounds*" (or simply "*high-molecular-compounds*", but it sounds ambiguously) tag.

I realize that tagspace is essentially a flatland, but "*high-molecular-weight-compounds*" seems more significant hierarchically and can cover not only polymers, but also biopolymers, DNA–RNA, some colloidal particles and polyoxometalates.

Comment: I think "colloidal materials" or similar would be a good tag (although somewhat old-fashioned word) but "high MW..." is *too ambiguous* or even *inaccurate* - would you call a vesicle a high MW compound?

Comment: Vesicle — no, but a polymer blob is a HMWC all right. That's why I put "*some*" before "colloidal particles":)

Comment: Ok, I missed that "some". But is "high-MW compound" better than colloid? Why choose one over the other (considering semantics - not exact choice of words, since "colloid" perhaps has better synonyms)? Perhaps "soft materials" or "mesoscopic materials" or other tag might be better.

Comment: Personally I like high MW compounds because it is clear that it refers to single molecules, but it then requires definition of a boundary with "low MW" compounds, introducing the ambiguity with respect to colloid and soft materials etc. Basically you want to generate a Venn diagram with the tags you attach to a post, and the less tags you need the better.

Comment: I never said that one tag is better or worse, I only suggested HMWC as probably the broadest one to cover as many neighboring fields as possible (yes, my answer is semi-offtopic, I realize that). I see "high-molecular-weight-compounds" relates to "polymers" like, say, "physical-chemistry" to "physical-organic-chemistry" or "electrochemistry": a larger sub-group. And yes, Venn diagram would be a bliss:)

Comment: It's on topic because the question is why get rid of "plastics", and therefore "why did *that* tag exist in the first place?" Leading to the question of redundancy, tag Venn diagrams etc :)

Comment: There is of course "macromolecules" - there's even an ACS journal for that. But then "biopolymers" and just "polymers" would coexist within that group.

Comment: "Macromolecules" (MM) is a good one, maybe you could add this as a suggestion to your answer? Basically similar to HMWC, but shorter.

Comment: We have a colloids tag already. I agree that macro-molecule could be a tag, but high-molecular weight-molecule is not intuitive and polymers are more that just a molecular weight. They have distinct mechanical behaviors that cannot be lumped into macro-molecules.

Comment: I'd say it suffices to define a polymer as a molecule containing a large number of repeating (monomeric) subunits, without reference to physicochemical properties (unlike "colloid"), although they do have those properties. But more importantly (or perhaps utterly unimportantly) I do think they are lumpable into macromolecules. I'll go check what the ACS has to say on this...

Comment: Macromolecules journal scope: "Macromolecules publishes original research on all fundamental aspects of macromolecular science including synthesis, polymerization mechanisms and kinetics, chemical modification, solution/melt/solid-state characteristics, and surface properties of organic, inorganic, and naturally occurring polymers. The papers showcase innovative concepts, experimental methods/observations, and theoretical approaches"