# Adding tag synonym for quantum mechanics -> quantum chemistry

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Since [this related thread](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391/divide-and-conquer-merging-theoretical-chemistry-quantum-chemistry-and-quantu) died out, I'd really like to add a tag synonym from 'quantum mechanics' -> 'quantum chemistry' since I think users are confused.

Should I just go do this? I mainly ask because I've only been active for a few weeks and don't want to ruffle feathers.

Comment: So quantum-chemistry would be the keeper, then?  I have to admit that I did lose track of that other discussion.  I've been wanting to do something with theoretical-chemistry for a while (as brought up in the other discussion), since it tends to get abused by new users.  I wouldn't do it just yet, but let's keep this on the front burner for a bit.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the way I'd go. This also creates a distinction from physics-related questions, which of course end up in Physics.SE instead of here.

Comment: After all.. we don't usually see quantum teleportation or entanglement questions here.

Comment: What do you think about theoretical-chemistry?  Good, bad, ugly?

Comment: I'd like Martin to weigh in since he planned out the scheme in the other question, and I don't know if his vision has changed.

Comment: @jonsca I think theoretical-chemistry is ugly right now, but might have some purpose as the site grows. I think we should table that discussion and see if we can just simplify this issue for now.

Comment: @jonsca I also always wanted to do something about these tags. I am on a business trip right now so I keep it short for the moment. The use of theo-chem is still ugly and needs a lot work done. Since we have quite some members in the community working in the field I have no worries about dealing with this subject. Maybe a special chat would help. On the easily to accomplished side I would go for merging the quantum tags, seconding geoff's question. We should still look through those questions and retag where appropriate.

Comment: Last time we did a major merge I ended up editing a lot of questions, unfortunately burying all the new ones. We should proceede with care this time. I think jonsca can do the merge without upsetting the balance and we all can work on retagging if necessary over a longer timespan. I am currently not aware of the tag wiki progress, but i would suggest cleaning and extending this along the way, so that everyone has a handle on things. Last but not least i'd like to thank you for bringing this toppic up again.

Answer (score 5):

I went ahead and did the merge of the two tags.  I have also set [quantum-mechanics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-mechanics) as a synonym for [quantum-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-chemistry).

We can revisit the [theoretical-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theoretical-chemistry) at a later time, since as we've examined in the comments, it's not going to be as straightforward.

Comment: Thanks! This seems like a good idea.